# What exactly does it mean for a systemd service to be "activating"?

Tags: systemd, services, systemd-unit

According to various clauses in the docs, the "activating" state is the transition between inactive states and an active state. So far so obvious.

But how exactly is it defined?
What determines whether a service is no longer inactive but activating?
What determines whether a service is no longer activating but active?

The only thing I know of that plays into the "activating" state is the `ExecStartPre` script; while it is running, the service remains "activating".

Are there other means to cause a service to remain in an activating state?

Could you have the service start the primary `ExecStart` but only consider the service active once the executable causes some specific "I'm up!" event for instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> while it is running, the service remains "activating".

That would indicate you're using the wrong `Type=` for your service file. See `man systemd.unit` and `systemd.service` for a pretty detailed discussion on when what service is called started. The text is too long to reasonably copy & paste in here, but from the `Type=` description in `man systemd.service`:

> `Type=`
>
> Configures the mechanism via which the service notifies the
> manager that the service start-up has finished. One of
> simple, exec, forking, oneshot, dbus, notify, notify-reload,
> or idle:
>
> - If set to `simple` (the default if `ExecStart=` is specified
>   but neither `Type=` nor `BusName=` are), the service manager
>   will consider the unit started immediately after the main
>   service process has been forked off (i.e. immediately
>   after `fork()`, and before various process attributes have
>   been configured and in particular before the new process
>   has called `execve()` to invoke the actual service binary).
>   Typically, `Type=exec` is the better choice, see below.
> - The `exec` type is similar to simple, but the service                manager will consider the unit started immediately after
>   the main service binary has been executed.[…]
> - If set to `forking`, the manager will consider the unit
>   started immediately after the binary that forked off by
>   the manager exits.  The use of this type is discouraged,
>   use `notify`, `notify-reload`, or `dbus` instead […]
> - Behavior of `oneshot` is similar to `simple`; however, the
>   service manager will consider the unit up after the main
>   process exits. […]
>
> [… and the bus-/notification-based schemes…]

So, there's different points in time when your service goes from "activating" to "active", depending on how it's set up. "activating" however always starts at the same point: the moment systemd begins to do whatever is specified in service file.

Comment: The service type is correct. This sentence was specifically concerning `ExecStartPre` and I would expect a service of any type to be considered "activating" while `ExecStartPre` is running.

Comment: Would you mind if I edited your answer to remove this confusion and add a section on the `Type=notify` which answers my last question?

Comment: I don't really understand your two comments! So I think, it might be wiser if you posted your own answer – feel free to refer to mine, if it helps :) Accepting your own answer is totally OK on here.